# Is there a way to apply filters on a count function in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My use case is as follows - I have a topic containing messages which a specific ID. 
I've created a Kafka Streams application which aggregates messages with the same ID and counts them (similarly to the example WordCount implementation in https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/tutorial)

I would like the Kafka stream to send a message to the output topic only when a certain threshold was exceeded. For example, if I define the threshold to be 10, I want a message to be sent to the output topic once 10 messages with the same ID were processed by the stream.

I understand that this could be done by having an additional topic and another stream that would process that topic, but is there any way to do this in a single stream?

Comment: Your "single stream" is more of a KTable.. You'll need another topic here, but "filter" is the wrong word you're looking for. Try `Punctuator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After converting the KStream to a  Stream using the count() aggregation function, it is possible to filter the count value, convert it to a Stream and send to a specific topic:

```
.selectKey((k, v) -> v)
        .groupByKey()
        .count()
        .filter((key, count) -> count > 3)
        .toStream()
        .filter((key, count) -> count != null)
        .to("output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
```

Comment: You can also apply a filter to the result `KTable` directly via `KTable#filter()`. Btw: you might want to mark your own answer as accepted :)